Salt script local copy multiple files from one dir to another
I wanted to copy multiple files (file names and number of files are dynamic) from one dir to another locally within a minion. Expecting equivalent of below.
cp /app/downloaded/*.* /app/myapp/installables/.

Destination dir already exists. Previous version files are required to be retained at the destination and so I cannot delete destination dir or the existing files there.
I think I am missing something simple. Please can anyone help.
Tried the below
Copy_new_version_files_for_installation:
  file.copy:
    - name: /app/myapp/installables
    - source: /app/downloaded
    - recurse: True


but getting
          ID: Copy_new_version_files_for_installation
    Function: file.copy
        Name: /app/myapp/installables
      Result: True
     Comment: The target file "/app/myapp/installables" exists and will not be overwritten



Looks like this is a confusion between the execution module and state module.
To use execution module from within state (SLS) files, we need to specify module.run. Otherwise Saltstack will try to run the file.copy state.
Below example should work:
Copy_new_version_files_for_installation:
  module.run:
  - file.copy:
    - dst: /app/myapp/installables
    - src: /app/downloaded
    - recurse: True


I don't see the file.copy state take recurse argument as per documentation. They might do the same thing, but how it needs to be defined in state file is what i've explained in my answer.

Use the rsync.sycnronized state to ensure one directory contains a copy of everything in another.
Copy new version files for installation:
  rsync.sycnronized:
    - name: /app/myapp/installables
    - source: /app/downloaded

It avoids making unnecessary copies on every run.
